# How to get value of closest hidden input field on button click

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a loop ie: each delete button and csrf token shows as many times as there are database records:

```
<% for (const products of approved) { %>
<li>
    <div class="list-box-listing">
        <div class="list-box-listing-img"><a href="#"><img src="../<%= products.image %>" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="list-box-listing-content">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3><a href="#"><%= products.title %></a></h3>
                <span><%= products.address.city %>, <%= products.address.suburb %></span>
                <div class="star-rating">
                    <h5>Added <%= moment(products.createdAt).fromNow() %></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-to-right">
        <a href="edit-listing/<%= products._id %>" class="button gray edit"><i class="sl sl-icon-note"></i> Edit</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
        <a href="#" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>
<% } %>
```

I want to get the value of the csrf token that is in the same vicinity as the button that was clicked.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!e.target.matches(".delete")) return;
  e.preventDefault();


  const deleteBtn = e.target;
  const csrf = document.querySelector("[name=_csrf").value;
  const productId = deleteBtn.dataset.id;

  console.log(csrf);

});
```

I tried using 'closest' but that was an epic fail.

```
  const deleteBtn = e.target;
  const csrf = deleteBtn.closest("[name=_csrf]").value;
```

I also tried:

```
const csrf = deleteBtn.parentNode.querySelector("[name=_csrf]").value;
```

But that gives me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>       at HTMLBodyElement.document.body.addEventListener.e

Comment: what document.querySelector("[name=_csrf").value giving you?

Comment: It gives me a value for the csrf token field but not the closest one to the button I pressed.

Comment: Why are you attaching the `click` event listener on `document.body` level?

Comment: @jom, because I have multiple records from the database so I can't target the class directly (as far as I know) ie: I can't do `document.querySelector('.delete')` as then the click only works for the first record and none after that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling

Comment: There seems to be a problem somewhere else. When I look at the rendered html once the page has loaded the hidden field isn't even there! Will update my original question

Comment: This is doable via vanilla Javascript, but are you open for jQuery solutions?

Comment: I know how to do it in jQuery but am trying to use vanilla javascript. yes, making my life difficult but doing it via javascript isn't that bad, when I can get it working!

Comment: It isn't bad at all, just makes life easier, yes.

Comment: Guess I am just trying to prove a point to myself that I can do it without jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the demos the `e.currentTarget` has changed from:

> ```
> document.body.addEventListener(...
> ```

***to:***

> ```
> document.querySelector('.buttons-to-right').addEventListener(...
> ```

Use `previousElementSibling`, see **Demo 1**. If that doesn't work, try using `e.currentTarget` and then get a reference from there, see **Demo 2**. BTW you can apply the following to `<a>`nchors that are used for buttons:

> ```
> <a href="#/" ...
> ```

The forward slash `/` disables the default behavior of jumping so you don't have to use `e.preventDefault()`.

---

### Demo 1

```js
const getCSRF = e => {

  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".delete")) {

    const input = tgt.previousElementSibling;
    const csrf = input.value;
    const productId = tgt.dataset.id;

    console.log(csrf);
  }
};

document.querySelector('.buttons-to-right').addEventListener("click", getCSRF);
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="list-box-listing">
    <div class="list-box-listing-img"><a href="#"><img src="../<%= products.image %>" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="list-box-listing-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </h3>
        <span></span>
        <div class="star-rating">
          <h5>Added </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-to-right">
    <a href="edit-listing/<%= products._id %>" class="button gray edit"><i class="sl sl-icon-note"></i> Edit</a>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
    <a href="#/" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
const getCSRF = e => {

  const tgt = e.target;
  const cur = e.currentTarget;

  if (tgt.matches(".delete")) {

    const input = cur.querySelector('[name=_csrf]');
    const csrf = input.value;
    const productId = tgt.dataset.id;

    console.log(csrf);
  }

};

document.querySelector('.buttons-to-right').addEventListener("click", getCSRF);
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="list-box-listing">
    <div class="list-box-listing-img"><a href="#"><img src="../<%= products.image %>" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="list-box-listing-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </h3>
        <span></span>
        <div class="star-rating">
          <h5>Added </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-to-right">
    <a href="edit-listing/<%= products._id %>" class="button gray edit"><i class="sl sl-icon-note"></i> Edit</a>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">

    <a href="#/" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for that. I can see it works in your snippet but when I run it on my side I get 'undefined' in console?

Comment: I thought previousElementSibling was meant to get the same type of element? Like if you have 2 <li> and you want to get the first one for example.

Comment: It's `tagName` blind an element is an element as far as it's concerned. You double checked the layout and made sure there's no `<br>`s in between or anything else?

Comment: I have gone ahead and changed my original question to include the whole loop. Perhaps there is something wrong in my whole block of code there that I missed

Comment: I also tried this: `const csrf = deleteBtn.parentNode.querySelector("[name=_csrf]").value;` but that gives me error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLBodyElement.document.body.addEventListener.e

Comment: I am very embarrassed right now. I was working on the wrong html file. I have 2 very similar. Your code works great

Comment: That's great I'm glad you caught that, a lot of people don't recover so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the containing element and query for the target field, like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.delete').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var csrf = this.parentElement.querySelector('[name="_csrf"]').value;

    console.log(csrf);
  });
});
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="list-box-listing">
    <div class="list-box-listing-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="product-image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-box-listing-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3><a href="#">Product title 1</a></h3>
        <span>Address 2</span>
        <div class="star-rating">
          <h5>Added 01/15/2019</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-to-right">
    <a href="edit-listing/1" class="button gray edit"><i class="sl sl-icon-note"></i> Edit</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="TOKEN_VALUE_1">
    <a href="#" class="button gray delete" data-id="123"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="list-box-listing">
    <div class="list-box-listing-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="product-image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-box-listing-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3><a href="#">Product title 2</a></h3>
        <span>Address 2</span>
        <div class="star-rating">
          <h5>Added 01/15/2019</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-to-right">
    <a href="edit-listing/1" class="button gray edit"><i class="sl sl-icon-note"></i> Edit</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="TOKEN_VALUE_2">
    <a href="#" class="button gray delete" data-id="456"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, I appreciate it. My problem actually had nothing to do with javascript. I was being thick and using the wrong html file as I have 2 very similar (icon with face in hands goes here)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :). And here's your *#facepalm* icon ‍♂️

Comment: Hahaha, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.

```
    <script>
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (!e.target.matches(".delete")) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        const deleteBtn = e.target;
        const closestDiv = deleteBtn.closest("[class=buttons-to-right]");
        const csrf = closestDiv.querySelector("[name=_csrf]").value;
        console.log(csrf);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. That gives me an error: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: pls change this line
-----
`const csrf = closestDiv.querySelector("[name=_csrf]").value;`

Comment: change it to what? You have posted the exact same code in your comment as your answer? Unless I am not looking properly...

Comment: i just forget to  add ] in  closestDiv.querySelector("[name=_csrf before this so.

Comment: I have this now but still get the same error `const closestDiv = deleteBtn.closest("[class=buttons-to-right]");
  const csrf = closestDiv.querySelector("[name=_csrf]").value;`